# ERROR FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app)

Tags: angular, firebase

Please i keep having this error and i am initializing firebase in my app module. please is there anything i'm doing wrong, i have read multiple documentation

## App.module.ts

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { environment } from './services/auth.service';
initializeApp(environment.firebase);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    CloudinaryModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    HomeModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

## firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.1.0/firebase-app-compat.js"
);
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.1.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js"
);
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "config data from general tab",
  authDomain: "config data from general tab",
  projectId: "config data from general tab",
  storageBucket: "config data from general tab",
  messagingSenderId: "config data from general tab",
  appId: "config data from general tab",
  measurementId: "config data from general tab",
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

## app.component.ts

```
import { getMessaging, getToken, onMessage } from 'firebase/messaging';
import { environment } from './services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'moniepassweb';
message!: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    const cld = new Cloudinary({ cloud: { cloudName: 'dpa8pui0l' } });
    this.requestPermission();
    this.listen();
  }
  requestPermission() {
    const messaging = getMessaging();
    getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: environment.firebase.vapidKey })
      .then((currentToken) => {
        if (currentToken) {
          console.log('Hurraaa!!! we got the token.....');
          console.log(currentToken);
        } else {
          console.log(
            'No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.'
          );
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
      });
  }
  listen() {
    const messaging = getMessaging();
    onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
      console.log('Message received. ', payload);
      this.message = payload;
    });
  }
}
```

i've tried everything i could possibly think off, also seen other issues on it in otther frameworks but none of the answers fit my issue, all i need is to get the token that is being genrated

Comment: Don't put your call to initializeApp into your service worker.

Comment: @MGX I already did that, and still no changes.